# psql import csv and generate uuid

Tags: postgresql, csv, psql

I'm trying to import from CSV to Postgres and generate a uuid, uuid_generate_v4(), during the import to populate a table.

Postgres version: 14

**Postgres Table**

- Country

  - id (primary key)
  - country_name
  - country_ISO_Code

**Psql import**

```
\copy "Country" (select uuid_generate_v4() as "id", "country_name", "country_ISO_code") FROM 'C:\Users\.......\data.csv' (format csv, header, delimiter ',')
```

However, that throws an error `\copy: parse error at "as"`

How do I properly instruct psql to use `uuid_generate_v4()` as id column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't copy "from" a select statement. You need to define a default value for your primary key:

```
create table country
(
  id uuid primary key default gen_random_uuid(),
  country_name text not null,
  country_iso_code text not null
);
```

Then tell the `\copy` command that your input file only contains two columns:

```
\copy country (country_name, country_iso_code) from 'data.csv' (format csv, header, delimiter ',')
```